# VSCode: "matplotlib" is not accessedPylance on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, conda, interpreter, pylance

When importing any module (matplotlib, geopandas, numpy, pysal, etc.) I get the message of "matplotlib" is not accessed Pylance

I have read other posts saying you need to direct VSCode to your interpreter, but my codespace is already directed at the interpreter that has the packages downloaded.
~anaconda3/bin/python3.11

But I still get the error where any module is not imported even though I have directed it at the proper interpreter.

Thank you

I have directed it at the interpreter many times and even tried switching interpreters and then reloading the page and nothing changes.

Comment: Your question is unclear. *When importing any module (matplotlib, geopandas, numpy, pysal, etc.) I get the message of "matplotlib" is not accessed Pylance* How do you get this message when import `numpy`, for instance? What is the actual, complete error message? Where you do see it (in popup window as a message from vscode, in a terminal window as a message from python when you run your program? Please provide more details to help us know what you are actually doing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.